# pgAdmin starting blank

Tags: pgadmin-4

I have installed the x64 version of PostgreSQL-9.6 using the installer by EnterpriseDB, which also installed pgAdmin 4. However, when pgAdmin starts, it hangs for a few seconds and then gives me this:[image]:
The PostgreSQL service is running, and I also checked it with pg_isready. Everything is happening on my machine (no remote stuff). Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Does running the program in [compatibility mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15078/windows-make-older-programs-compatible) help?

Comment: @kennytm, strange. It very briefly displays "Connecting to the application server" and then the same thing as before. Could it be the Windows firewall?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56405497/pgadmin-4-7-displays-blank-popup-screen-on-startup
>this solution works

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by right-clicking within the blank pane, choosing stop, right-clicking again, and choosing reload.