# pgAdmin 4.7 displays blank popup screen on startup

Tags: pgadmin-4

I've just installed latest pgAdmin (4.7) and whenever I start it up I get this strange blank popup which I can not remove:
[image]

I can use the application just fine I just need to move that empty window to the side which is annoying.
I'm using Firefox version 67 (64bit).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56405600/8519202 This answer works for pgAdmin v4.15 too.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I've solved the issue by resetting the layout from the pgAdmin menu.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It helped me sort out the issue.

Comment: It's worth saying that I had an empty popup every time after running a sql query in pgadmin and this answer resolved that too.